# Let $\Bbb S$ denote the sorgenfrey plane. Are two lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ always homeomorphic with regards to this topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\Bbb S$ denote the sorgenfrey plane. That is the space $(\Bbb R^2, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is generated by $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a < b, c < d \}.$ Are two lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ always homeomorphic with regards to this topology?

I've been trying to understand the question, but it doesn't make much sense. We can write $\ell_1=\{(x,y) \mid y = mx+b \}$ and $\ell_2=\{(x,y) \mid y = kx+c\}$. The question now asks whether I can always find a map $f : \ell_1 \to \ell_2$ such that it's an homeomorphism.

Is there some canonical way to define $f$, can I just take $f(x,mx+b) = (x,kx+c)$?

Comment: It is good to give a reference to [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) to remind what it is.

Comment: @Anne Bauval 1) Thank you for pointing the erroneous link. 2) I think good that a text is self-contained and give easily access to a first reference, a reminder when one has forgotten this "sans-souci" mathematician :)

Comment: Hint: look at the induced topology on the line $\{(x,-x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. Is is the same as the topology induced on, say, the line $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$?

Comment: It's discrete on $\{(x,-x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, but not on $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. Does this imply that the statement is not true? @AlessandroCodenotti